# 18.04 USB Ethernet adapters - how to fix cloning

Tags: networking, network-manager, android, usb-modem, tethering

I have one **Android** phone which has USB hotspot feature (tethering).
Steps that reproduce the problem:

1. I connect phone to Ubuntu.
2. Make changes to **USB Ethernet** adapter in Settings => Network, like changing DNS servers or disabling IPv6 or anything else.
3. Reboot PC.
4. Look at new USB Ethernet adapter is in the list!
5. Make changes again, to a new adapter this time. (Wired connection 2)
6. Reboot PC.
7. Look at new USB Ethernet adapter is in the list!
8. Make changes again, to a new adapter this time. (Wired connection 3)
9. Reboot PC.
10. Look at new USB Ethernet adapter is in the list!
11. Make changes again, to a new adapter this time. (Wired connection 4)
12. Reboot PC.
13. Look at new USB Ethernet adapter is in the list!
14. Make changes again, to a new adapter this time. (Wired connection 5)

How to avoid this replication?
A garbage list right in the Settings control panel.

P.S. all these wired connections have the same MAC address.

Comment: Instead of editing the new connection each time can you just connect to one you configured the first time?

Comment: **Ryan J. Yoder**, I tried, but all previous connections are unavailable to connect to.